# Issue with setting up JavaMail for IMAP

Tags: java, protocols, imap, jakarta-mail

I am trying to connect to my company's Exchange server using an app that I have written. I have searched for 2 days straight and I can't figure out why it won't work.

First, here is my code:

```
      String to = "you@yours.com";
      String from = "me@mine.com";
      String host = "mail.exchange.server.net";
final String username = "me@mine.com";
final String password = "password";
      String provider = "imap";

      Properties props = new Properties();
//        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
      props.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
//        props.put("mail.smtp.user", username);
//        props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
      props.put("mail.imap.port", "143");
//        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    //Removed to simplify method//

//        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
//          @Override
//          protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
//              return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
//          }
//        };

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);      
    Store store = session.getStore(provider);

    try {
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
        msg.setSubject("Test");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText("This works.");
        Transport transport = session.getTransport();
        transport.connect(username, password);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        Transport.send(msg);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, address);
        if (transport == null) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Mail carrier was shot. Sorry.");
        }
```

I am trying to keep this as simple as possible. No SSL, no IMAPS, no Authenticator, nothing fancy. It refuses to accept a provider. It kicks back a message (via `System.err.println`) that says "Invalid provider" or "provider null". I am under the assumption that just the JavaMail API has enough in it to connect to a plain, vanilla Exchange server using the IMAP protocol.

Here is what I am getting:

```
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Invalid protocol: null
    at javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:449)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:667)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:648)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:634)
```

To me, it seems like JavaMail doesn't have anything for IMAP and I will have to import another lib into my project. Does anyone see what is going on?

*Ero addendum:* I can establish a session through my cell phone, iPad, and laptop. That leads me to believe that it is not a port or connectivity issue. I am just trying to connect to the server, for the time being. I can hammer out the details of authentication later.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to send and email but you don't setup a transport server in your properties...

Something like:

```
props.put("mail.host", "mysmtp.com");
props.put ("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
```